# How to properly add dummy variables as controls when the independent variable is a dummy variable?

Tags: multiple-regression, multicollinearity, categorical-encoding, finance

I am writing a thesis where I investigate whether ESG/sustainable funds' decision to invest in fossil fuels/weapons affects fund flows.

I am regressing a fund flow variable on a dummy variable x which takes the value of 0 if a fund invests in fossil fuels/weapons and 1 if the fund does not invest. So:

y=β0+β1(0) -> flows predicted for funds which invest in fossil fuels/weapons

y=β0+β1(1) -> flows predicted for funds which do not invest

I want to include Morningstar's sustainability rating as a control. This rating is measured in "globes" from 1-5, 5 globes being the best.

To do this, I want to add a set of dummy variables, as that is what the authors of another paper did (they found that this rating had an effect on fund flows). The authors of this paper omitted the three-globe category, to avoid the dummy variable trap.

If I follow this same approach, will the effect of the three-globe category, the one I don't create the dummy variable for, be captured by β0, which I was using to predict the flows of funds which do invest in fossil fuels/weapons?

If yes, how can I capture the effect of the three-globe category separately without falling into the dummy variable trap?

Comment: How exactly you do this depends on which software you are using. You can certainly do it in R, SAS, and Python. I'm guessing you can do it in just about any statistical software. But the method will be different. 

This question might belong on Stack Overflow, or on a site devoted to your software.

Comment: Welcome to cv, Christian! I do understand your question as a genuinely statistical question and not about implementation, because you are asking about the consequences of removing one category from a categorical variable (would you agree, @PeterFlom ?). I am wondering how you get to the decision to remove the three-globe category - is it because the authors you refer to have done so? If yes, could you give the reference in your question (maybe a link)? Did you check your data if there is multicollinearity if you keep that dummy variable?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. I do not have time to write an answer now, but this might be of interest to you: https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/spss/faq/coding-systems-for-categorical-variables-in-regression-analysis/

Comment: @Ute Yes, it was because the authors I referred to did that in order to have n-1 dummies. We did check for multicollinearity using VIFs and didn't find cause for concern there. But according to some other people I've asked for help, it doesn't matter that B0 is catching the effects of the three-globes and the decision to invest since we are more interested in B1, which tells us whether the flows are meaningfully higher/lower for the funds which don't invest.

Comment: @PeterFlom I was more concerned from a statistics POV, whether it's a problem that B0 is capturing more than one effect. But B1 is much more important.

Comment: Do you get very different results with and without that three-globes category dummy variable?